# input objects in powershell jobs

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to implement a job in PowerShell that would look something like this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential 
$job1 = Start-Job -InputObject $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ADUser -Credential $cred -Filter *
}
$res1 = Wait-Job -Job $job1 | Receive-Job
```

But I am receiving an error message:

"Wait-Job : The Wait-Job cmdlet cannot finish working, because one or more jobs are blocked waiting for user interaction.  Process interactive job output by using the Receive-Job cmdlet, and then try again.
....
Deadlock detected: (System.Manageme...n.PSRemotingJob:PSRemotingJob) [Wait-J 
   ob], 
....
"

But if I create this seemingly identical job like this:

```
$job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    $pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "usr",$pass

    Get-ADUser -Credential $cred -Filter *
}
$res2 = Wait-Job -Job $job2 | Receive-Job
```

Everything works perfectly.

Can you please help me understand why?

Thanks!

Comment: From TechNet: In the value of the ScriptBlock parameter, use the `$input` automatic variable to represent the input objects. or what zdan said

Answer (score 2):

To pass arguments to the script block, you need to use the `-ArgumentList` parameter, not `-InputObject`. Try this:

```
$cred = Get-Credential 
$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {PARAM($cred)
    Get-ADUser -Credential $cred -Filter *
} -ArgumentList $cred
```

Note that `-ArgumentList` has to be the last parameter in the `Start-Job` command.

Comment: This is honestly how I deal with passing variables into a job's scriptblock, I just added my answer since it directly addressed the exact issue the user was facing with their script.

Comment: *Note that -ArgumentList has to be the last parameter in the Start-Job command.* Can you provide reference for this claim? AFAIK, order of named parameters is irrelevant.

Comment: @PetSerAl See the [help for Start-Job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx), under `-ArgumentList` it states" _Because all of the values that follow the ArgumentList parameter name are interpreted as being values of ArgumentList, the ArgumentList parameter should be the last parameter in the command._

Comment: Apparently documentation bug. `Start-Job -ArgumentList 1,2,3,4,5 -ScriptBlock {$args}`. Named parameter accept at most one expression (although it can be array expression) as parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this would probably be evident if you had but read the Help for `Start-Job`. If you use the `-InputObject` argument you then reference it from within the scriptblock with the automatic variable `$Input`. Since you reference `$Cred` out of scope like that it's trying to get credentials again. Here's the Help text for that parameter.

```
-InputObject <PSObject>
    Specifies input to the command. Enter a variable that contains the objects, or type a command or expression that generates the objects.

    In the value of the ScriptBlock parameter, use the $input automatic variable to represent the input objects.
```

You could alter your script to look like this and it should work fine:

```
$cred = Get-Credential 
$job1 = Start-Job -InputObject $cred -ScriptBlock {
    Get-ADUser -Credential $Input -Filter *
}
$res1 = Wait-Job -Job $job1 | Receive-Job
```