# Using Credential breaks the script block

Tags: sql-server, powershell, start-job

Overview: This is a PowerShell script created to automate SQL database backup which must be done in parallel as much as possible.

This works fine.

```
$ServerInstanceSource = ".\INSTANCE01"
$ServerInstanceDestination = ".\INSTANCE02"
$UserName = 'user'
$PassWord = 'pass'

$GetDBs = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstanceSource -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Database tempdb -Query "SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND recovery_model_desc != 'SIMPLE'"
$Date =  (Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddhhmmss')
$BackupSourceDirectory = 'F:\DB-BACKUP\SQLBACKUP\Manual Logshipping Restoration\'
$BackupDestinationDirectory = 'D:\BACKUPS\'

Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force

Write-Output "Creating FULL backup. . ."

ForEach($db in $GetDBs.name){
    $FileName = "FULL-$db-$Date.bak"
    $FullBackupPath = Join-Path -Path $BackupSourceDirectory -ChildPath $FileName
    $BackupFullScript = "BACKUP DATABASE $db TO DISK = N'$FullBackupPath' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'$db-FULL Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10"
    $SQLBackupFull = "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstanceSource -Username $UserName -Password $Password -Database tempdb -Query `"$BackupFullScript`" -QueryTimeout 21600;" # 5 hours
    [scriptblock]$cmdblock1 = [ScriptBlock]::Create($SQLBackupFull)
    Start-Job $cmdblock1
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

However, when I converted the code to accept credentials instead of hard coded ones, I'm getting errors:

```
$ServerInstanceSource = ".\INSTANCE01"
$ServerInstanceDestination = ".\INSTANCE02"
$Cred = Get-Credential

$GetDBs = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstanceSource -Credential $Cred -Database tempdb -Query "SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 AND recovery_model_desc != 'SIMPLE' -- Dynamic; Input specific databases only, if necessary."
$Date =  (Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddhhmmss')
$BackupSourceDirectory = 'C:\Users\edgar.bayron\Music\Edgar\Trash Can\DB-BACKUP\SQLBACKUP\LAX-DBMON\' # "F:\DB-BACKUP\SQLBACKUP\Manual Logshipping Restoration\"
$BackupDestinationDirectory = 'C:\Users\edgar.bayron\Music\Edgar\Trash Can\DB-BACKUP\SQLBACKUP\DAL-INDBS01\' # "D:\BACKUPS\"

Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force

Write-Output "Creating FULL backup. . ."

ForEach($db in $GetDBs.name){
    $FileName = "FULL-$db-$Date.bak"
    $FullBackupPath = Join-Path -Path $BackupSourceDirectory -ChildPath $FileName
    $BackupFullScript = "BACKUP DATABASE $db TO DISK = N'$FullBackupPath' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'$db-FULL Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10"
    $SQLBackupFull = "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstanceSource -Credential $Cred -Database tempdb -Query `"$BackupFullScript`" -QueryTimeout 21600;" # 5 hours
    [scriptblock]$cmdblock1 = [ScriptBlock]::Create($SQLBackupFull)
    Start-Job $cmdblock1
}

Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job
```

Error:

```
Wait-Job : The Wait-Job cmdlet cannot finish working, because one or more jobs are blocked waiting for user interaction.  Process interactive job 
output by using the Receive-Job cmdlet, and then try again.
```

I'm trying to apply what was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33243714/input-objects-in-powershell-jobs), but I cannot fully apply it since in the example, it only has one parameter, while I have multiple. If I try to apply it, it searches for other variables.

I tried to use `{PARAM($ServerInstanceSource, $cred, $BackupFullScript)` but it breaks the SQL query inside `$BackupFullScript`.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Yes, well, `Get-Credential` prompts for credentials doesn't it? Have you looked at the [Get-Credential examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential?view=powershell-7.1#example-4) to see how to create `PSCredential` objects without prompting?

Comment: i can't see a good reason why I would use that method. For security purposes, I'm switching to using Get-Credential in order to remove hard-coded username and password in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use a credentials object as a string.  What happens is `$Cred` gets converted to a string using it's `.ToString()` method which will look like this `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` which obviously will not work when passed as the argument to the `-Credential` parameter in your scriptblock.

You can either return to your original implementation of using Username and Password where you can pass the username and password taken from the `$Cred` object

```
$SQLBackupFull = "Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstanceSource -Username $($Cred.UserName) -Password $($Cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password) -Database tempdb -Query `"$BackupFullScript`" -QueryTimeout 21600;" # 5 hours
```

or you can create a scriptblock with a `param()` block where you can pass in the `$Cred` object as an argument

*EDIT - the $cmd scriptblock moved out to before the foreach so it is only created once.*

```
$cmd = {
    param(
        $ServerInstanceSource,
        $Cred,
        $BackupFullScript
    )
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstanceSource -Credential $Cred -Database tempdb -Query $BackupFullScript -QueryTimeout 21600;
}

ForEach ($db in $GetDBs.name) {
    $FileName = "FULL-$db-$Date.bak"
    $FullBackupPath = Join-Path -Path $BackupSourceDirectory -ChildPath $FileName
    $BackupFullScript = "BACKUP DATABASE $db TO DISK = N'$FullBackupPath' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'$db-FULL Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10"

    Start-Job $cmd -ArgumentList $ServerInstanceSource, $Cred, $BackupFullScript
}
```

Comment: wow the 1st method worked. I didn't know I could do that one ($Cred.UserName). Would the 2nd method have advantage over the first one? I would also like to try that one. But it looks a bit more complicated than the 1st one. Anyway, big thanks !

Comment: Happy I could help.  I think you're fine with the first method.  I prefer the scriptblock with the param block where I can pass in the full objects as arguments and not have the code inside the scriptblock hardcoded, but whatever works.  The 2nd method may be slightly more secure because you are not passing around the password in cleartext, but I think the risk here is negligible.  Anyone reading this please correct me if I'm wrong.